# How to return number of iterations in for loop? PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function

I'm trying to return the number of times a for loop in postgreSQL has iterated.

table:

```
players(season_year,firstname, lastname, season_win, season_loss, playoff_win, playoff_loss)
```

What I'm attempting to do is use an aggregate to see which player has the most overall season wins SUM(p.season_win + p.playoff_win - p.season_loss - p.playoff_loss). Using this aggregate and the season year, I want to return what rank player with firstname = 'x' lastname = 'y' is in the win/loss differential. However, I cannot seem to understand how the for loop works.

Here is what I've attempted with what I've looked up online:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_player_rank(year INTEGER, firstn VARCHAR, lastn VARCHAR) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE player_rank INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR player_rank IN 
    SELECT p.season_year, p.lastname, p.firstname, SUM(season_win + playoff_win - season_loss - playoff_loss) as total_wins
    FROM player p
    GROUP BY p.year, p.lastname, p.firstname
    WHERE p.season_year = year LOOP
    IF(firstn = p.firstname AND lastn = p.lastname) THEN
        RETURN player_rank;
    END IF
    END LOOP
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I really appreciate any help I can get!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
-- ...
RETURN NEXT player_rank; -- return current row of SELECT
END IF
END LOOP
-- ...
```

See this for more info on return: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: Are these in your player table?? `season_win + playoff_win - season_loss - playoff_loss`. If so they should also have p.season_win , p.playoff_win , etc...

Comment: Whoops, I'll update my function real quick. Here's the problem with this solution. I'm attempting to return an integer, So if I look up player x, I simply want to return that they are the 2nd best player in the league for that season. The rest of the information doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh so you are trying to determine which player is the best based on `total_wins`. If so then (as you iterate through each record) you will have to store total_wins in a temporary variable and make that your current highest. You cal call it `highest_wins` or whatever. Then update  `highest_wins` if `total_wins` > `highest_wins` on subsequent loops. Finally when the loop is done then you will have the highest_wins and you can return that data.

Comment: Close, but I simply want to return a number. Let's say we're talking about hockey goalies, If I run get_player_rank(2015, 'Carey', 'Price')

my output should simply be: 1

Comment: If I was using C++ it'd be easier, I could order an array by total_wins and attempt to match the player name, if it was in a for loop I could return i if I declared for(int i = 0; i < array.size; i++)